# Using uPickle, how do I instantiate a case class from a JSON array of different number types?

Tags: upickle

I have an array in JSON that looks like this:

```
"[3.7434,23.4308,3,131.45,1687,1436,1680195035745932326,-13.5,7,11,0.18,1]"
```

I want to create out of that array a instance of a case class that has the following types:

```
Foo(Double,Double,Int,Float,Int,Int,Long,Float,Int,Int,Float,Int)
```

How do I do that using uPickle?

So far I have:

```
val simpleArray = """[3.7434,23.4308,3,131.45,1687,1436,1680195035745932326,-13.5,7,11,0.18,1]"""
val arr = read[ujson.Arr](simpleArray)
val foo = Foo(
  arr(0).num,
  arr(1).num,
  arr(2).num.toInt,
  arr(3).num.toFloat,
  arr(4).num.toInt,
  arr(5).num.toInt,
  arr(6).num.toLong,
  arr(7).num.toFloat,
  arr(8).num.toInt,
  arr(9).num.toInt,
  arr(10).num.toFloat,
  arr(11).num.toInt
)
```